# Spring Boot - Docker Container - Synchronize Sections of Code between Containers?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot app running in Docker in which I have a set of DB rows that, among which, I need to avert a race condition between instances of the app running in Docker containers. The app is stateless, but in this one area of code, I need to somehow synchronize between the Docker containers so that only one of them can perform this action at a time.

How can I synchronize between the containers so that only one at a time can perform this action?

Comment: an idea: "lock on" a db/table/row/column/"some object, which is available to each instance" ...

Comment: Version your rows that need to be updated and handle StaleObjectStateException gracefully should the race condition actually occur.